# Errors I get when I use sfdx to install Field Service Lightning in a scratch org

Tags: scratch-org, scratch-org-definition-file, fsl

I've followed the [guidance from this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/287218/65083) —  using this in my project-scratch-def.json:

```json
{
    "features": ["FieldService:1"],
    "settings": {
        "fieldServiceSettings": { "fieldServiceOrgPref": true }
    }
}
```

so that my shape-based scratch org does indeed have the Field Service feature enabled already when I initially launch my scratch org

However, I'm noticing if I create a list of installed packages by running `force:package:installed:list`, the `FSL` package is not listed. So, I attempt to run the appropriate command to install the Field Service package...

`sfdx force:package:install --package 04t................. -w 10`

It works and churns at the installation, reporting INPROGRESS, but eventually errors out like this:

```
ERROR running force:package:install:  Installation errors: 
1) (WorkOrder-FSL Work Order Layout) feedLayout is not supported for this layout, Details: WorkOrder-FSL Work Order Layout: feedLayout is not supported for this layout
2) (WorkOrderLineItem-FSL Work Order Line Item Layout) feedLayout is not supported for this layout, Details: WorkOrderLineItem-FSL Work Order Line Item Layout: feedLayout is not supported for this layout
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You also need to enable Chatter (Feeds). I'm not sure which setting that is, but you need it turned on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below settings to enable Chatter

```
{
"features": ["FieldService:1"],
"settings": {
    "fieldServiceSettings": {
        "fieldServiceOrgPref": true
    },
    "chatterSettings": {
        "enableChatter": true
    }
  }
}
```